# Check Javascript object undefined

Tags: javascript

**update**

I am trying to test to see whether a Javascript variable is undefined.

How to make an object that is missing a variable or undefined

before thank you if it is willing to help

**this my code**

```
var mydata = {
  p001: "Product 1",
  p002: "Product 2",
  p003: "Product 3"
}

function test(e) {
  if (mydata === undefined || mydata === null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<em>No data</em>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mydata[e];
  }
}
```

```js
var mydata = {
  p001: "Product 1",
  p002: "Product 2",
  p003: "Product 3"
}

function test(e) {
  if (mydata === undefined || mydata === null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<em>No data</em>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mydata[e];
  }
}
```

```css
#demo {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #2f9fd2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #daf3ff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick='test("p001");'>Product 1</button>
  <button onclick='test("p002");'>Product 2</button>
  <button onclick='test("p003");'>Product 3</button>
  <button onclick='test("p10000");'>Test undefined</button>
</p>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

sorry my English is not good

Thank you

Comment: Your code in the snippet works totally fine. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: `mydata` is an `Object`, not an `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Just check if there is no value for the key `e` in `mydata`.

By the way, there is no **array** here. Using the proper terms is important. You work with an **object** and you want to check if a property of it is defined or not.

```js
var mydata = {
 p001:"Product 1",
 p002:"Product 2",
 p003:"Product 3"
}

function test(e) {
  if (!mydata[e]) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<em>No data</em>"; 
 } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mydata[e];
 }
}
```

```css
#demo {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #2f9fd2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #daf3ff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick='test("p001");'>Product 1</button>
  <button onclick='test("p002");'>Product 2</button>
  <button onclick='test("p003");'>Product 3</button>
  <button onclick='test("p10000");'>Test undefined</button>
</p>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the check for `undefined` values.

```
if (mydata === undefined || mydata === null || mydata[e] === undefined) {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var mydata = {
 p001:"Product 1",
 p002:"Product 2",
 p003:"Product 3"
}

function test(e){
   if (mydata === undefined || mydata === null || mydata[e] === undefined) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<em>No data</em>"; 
 } 
    else {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mydata[e];
 }
}
```

```css
#demo {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #2f9fd2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #daf3ff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick='test("p001");'>Product 1</button>
  <button onclick='test("p002");'>Product 2</button>
  <button onclick='test("p003");'>Product 3</button>
  <button onclick='test("p10000");'>Test undefined</button>
</p>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no need of doing two check for the same thing like this:

```
if (mydata === undefined || mydata === null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<em>No data</em>"; 
    }
```

do this instead with a `==` operator cause basically `null` == `undefined` so this will eventually save you as `===` checks for an exact match but `==` will give you true for both `null` and `undefined` as it does the **type coercion** for you:

```
if (mydata == null){
    // your code here.
}
```